# set element opacity with user input in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-input, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable `div` and I want users to be able to set another div's opacity by typing in numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/w21q35tw/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#d').css("opacity", "val('"+$("#set").html()+"')"); //sets opacity - doesn't work
    $('#set').html(val('"+$("#set").html()+"')); //input stays as editable text - works
});
```

I had no problems with url inputs, but I have no success with neither val or attr in this case. I guess I'm failing to pick up val / attr from html.

How to solve this?

Comment: #d is the content editable div and #set is a textbox?  if #set is a textbox, shouldn't you use `.val()` instead?

Comment: What's this mysterious `val()` function you continue to use? Also, what's the last line in the click function's purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#d').css("opacity", $("#set").text() / 100);
    $('#set').val('"+$("#set").html()+"');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w21q35tw/1/  (Type 20 in the box for 20% opacity)

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks. I was also thinking that typing 50 is better than typing 0.5, so your answer hit the spot. I'll select your answer as soon as the site let me.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle, THIS IS THE RIGHT CODE: **http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/w21q35tw/2/**

I also added a check: if the users enters something wrong (e.g. 'cat' or -3) then it will alert "Wrong value!", here is the JavaScript code:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var opacity = +$('#set').text();
    if ((opacity === 0 || opacity > 0) && opacity <= 1) {
        $('#d').css("opacity", opacity);
        $('#set').html('');
    } else {
        alert('Wrong value!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#d').css("opacity", $("#set").text());
    $('#set').html(val('"+$("#set").html()+"'));
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your contenteditable `<div>` isn't a input form so it dont have a `val()`. Instead use the property .text() to get innerHTML value.

**Change**

```
$('#d').css("opacity", "val('"+$("#set").html()+"')");
```

**To**

```
$('#d').css("opacity", $("#set").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w21q35tw/3/).
You are making mistake while changing the CSS part:

1. Use `.text()` instead of .val() as it is the CONTENTEDITABLE div.
2. Second you are putting the quotes on wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is wrong. You need this:

```
$('#d').css("opacity", $("#set").html());
```